# Is there any REST API available to get list of schemas and list of tables in SAP HANA DB?

Tags: rest, hana

Is there any REST API available to get list of schemas and list of tables in SAP HANA DB?

I came across `/sap/hana/xs/dt/base/metadata/VIEW/RT/SCHEMAS` but this is listing metadata of `SCHEMAS` view only. `SYS.SCHEMAS` has list of all schemas, how can I retrieve that using REST API?

Comment: Are you able to resolve this? I'm in the similar situation where I need list of all tables in particular schema?